# Use LibVLC to adding subtitles permanent to video

Tags: uwp, libvlcsharp

I needs soem help with a feature I want to add to a UWP app.
I want to mix a video and a subtitle file (srt format) in a new video file so that I get one video file with the subtitles as an overlay to the original video.
The final result should look like vlc, when it has a video and a subtitle file with the same name in the same folder.

I have done this with a command line call of vlc with these parameters:

```
-I dummy {videofilename} --sub-file={subtitlefilename} --no-sub-autodetect-file --sout=#transcode{{vcodec=h264,vb=2048,acodec=mp4a,ab=192,channels=2,soverlay}}:standard{{access=file,mux=ts,dst={newvidefilename}}
```

I do not know hwo to do the same in an UWP app.
I have tried it with this code

```
           Core.Initialize();
            var option = $":sout=#transcode{{vcodec=mp2v,vb=4096,scale=1,acodec=mp2a,ab=192,channels=2,soverlay}}:std{{access=file,mux=ts,dst={outputfile}}}";
            var liboptions = new string[]
            {
                    $"--sout-file-overwrite",
                    $"--no-sub-autodetect-file"
            };
            var vlcLIB = new LibVLC(liboptions);
            mprec = new MediaPlayer(vlcLIB);
            mprec.Stopped += Mprec_Stopped;
            mrec = new Media(vlcLIB, inputStream);
            mrec.AddOption(option);
            mprec.AddSlave(MediaSlaveType.Subtitle, $"\"{srtFileFullName}\"", true);
            var r = mprec.Play(mrec);
```

This code creates a converted video with video and audio but what is missing is the subtitle overlay.
The files are in folders that are readable/writeable for the app. So it is not an access issue.
Any help on this is highly appreciated.
Using the log parameter in vlclib gives this output but that does not give me any hint why there are no subtitles.

```
Using the log option gives this output:
VLC media player - 3.0.16 Vetinari
Copyright © 1996-2021 the VideoLAN team
configured with /builds/videolan/libvlc-nuget/vlc/extras/package/win32/../../../configure  '--enable-update-check' '--enable-goom' '--enable-libcddb' '--enable-nls' '--host=i686-w64-mingw32' '--with-contrib=../contrib/i686-w64-mingw32uwp' '--disable-nls' '--disable-vlc' '--disable-qt' '--disable-skins2' '--enable-winstore-app' '--disable-vcd' '--disable-gl' '--disable-crystalhd' '--disable-dxva2' '--enable-lua' '--disable-vlm' '--disable-faad' '--enable-theora' '--disable-twolame' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-merge-ffmpeg' '--disable-dca' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-libass' '--disable-x264' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-live555' '--enable-shout' '--disable-goom' '--disable-caca' '--enable-sse' '--enable-mmx' '--disable-libcddb' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-telx' '--disable-mad' '--disable-a52' '--enable-dsm' '--disable-smbclient' '--enable-flac' '--enable-jpeg' '--enable-vpx' '--disable-postproc' '--enable-gme' 'host_alias=i686-w64-mingw32' 'CFLAGS= -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0xE00 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 -DWINVER=0x0A00 -DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -DWINSTORECOMPAT  -Wl,-lwindowsapp,-lwindowsappcompat -Wl,-lvcruntime140_app,-lucrt' 'LDFLAGS= -lwindowsapp -lwindowsappcompat -lvcruntime140_app -lucrt' 'CPPFLAGS= -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0xE00 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 -DWINVER=0x0A00 -DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -DWINSTORECOMPAT' 'CXXFLAGS= -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0xE00 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 -DWINVER=0x0A00 -DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -DWINSTORECOMPAT  -Wl,-lwindowsapp,-lwindowsappcompat -Wl,-lvcruntime140_app,-lucrt' 'PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config' 'PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/i686-w64-mingw32/pkgconfig'
creating audio output
using audio output module "winstore"
keeping audio output
looking for audio output module matching "winstore": 4 candidates
Generator log - Add slave returns:False
Creating an input for 'imem://'
'SubtitleGenerator.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.NetCoreApp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x5444 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2b64 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4a48 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5f38 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5c0c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5fd0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1e30 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xc6c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
using sout chain=`transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=4096,scale=1,acodec=mp2a,ab=192,channels=2}:std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=C:\Users\frank\AppData\Local\Packages\c8e7ca88-7e68-45b6-80bb-9d3c1a5a38e1_h68e2gsmfdepg\TempState\video.mp4}'
stream=`std'
looking for sout stream module matching "std": 22 candidates
file access output opened (C:\Users\frank\AppData\Local\Packages\c8e7ca88-7e68-45b6-80bb-9d3c1a5a38e1_h68e2gsmfdepg\TempState\video.mp4)
set config option: sout-standard-dst to C:\Users\frank\AppData\Local\Packages\c8e7ca88-7e68-45b6-80bb-9d3c1a5a38e1_h68e2gsmfdepg\TempState\video.mp4
set config option: sout-standard-access to file
muxer support adding stream at any time
muxer prefers to wait for all ES before starting to mux
using `file/ts://C:\Users\frank\AppData\Local\Packages\c8e7ca88-7e68-45b6-80bb-9d3c1a5a38e1_h68e2gsmfdepg\TempState\video.mp4'
using sout stream module "stream_out_standard"
stream=`transcode'
looking for sout stream module matching "transcode": 22 candidates
set config option: sout-transcode-vcodec to mp2v
set config option: sout-transcode-vb to 4096
set config option: sout-transcode-scale to 1
set config option: sout-transcode-acodec to mp2a
set config option: sout-transcode-ab to 192
set config option: sout-transcode-channels to 2
Checking codec mapping for mp2a got mpga 
codec audio=mpga 0Hz 2 channels 192Kb/s
Checking video codec mapping for mp2v got mp2v 
codec video=mp2v 0x0 scaling: 1.000000 4096kb/s
'SubtitleGenerator.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.30316.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Memory.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
using sout stream module "stream_out_transcode"
using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
using default timeshift path
`imem://' gives access `imem' demux `any' path `'
creating demux: access='imem' demux='any' location='' file='(null)'
looking for access_demux module matching "imem": 6 candidates
Invalid get/release function pointers
'SubtitleGenerator.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.30316.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Buffers.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
no access_demux modules matched
creating access: imem://
looking for access module matching "imem": 24 candidates
using access module "imem_access"
looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 22 candidates
Using stream method for AStream*
starting pre-buffering
looking for sout access module matching "file": 10 candidates
set config option: sout-standard-mux to ts
using sout access module "file"
looking for sout mux module matching "ts": 11 candidates
using sout mux module "mux_ts"
shaping=200000 pcr=70000 dts_delay=400000
received first data after 174 ms
using stream_filter module "cache_read"
pre-buffering done 1024 bytes in 0s - 5 KiB/s
Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\frank\AppData\Local\Packages\c8e7ca88-7e68-45b6-80bb-9d3c1a5a38e1_h68e2gsmfdepg\LocalState\vlc\lua\playlist
no stream_directory modules matched
attachment of directory-extractor failed for imem://
using stream_filter module "record"
looking for demux module matching "any": 51 candidates
creating demux: access='imem' demux='any' location='' file='(null)'
looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 22 candidates
looking for stream_directory module matching "any": 1 candidates
looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 22 candidates
no stream_filter modules matched
dumping root Box "root"
|   |   + mvhd size 108 offset 20957854
|   |   |   |   + elst size 28 offset 20958070
|   |   |   + mdia size 19440 offset 20958098
|   |   |   |   + mdhd size 32 offset 20958106
|   |   |   |   + hdlr size 45 offset 20958138
|   |   |   |   + minf size 19355 offset 20958183
|   |   |   |   |   + vmhd size 20 offset 20958191
|   |   |   |   |   + dinf size 36 offset 20958211
|   |   |   |   |   |   + dref size 28 offset 20958219
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   + url  size 12 offset 20958235
|   |   |   |   |   + stbl size 19291 offset 20958247
|   |   |   |   |   |   + stsd size 147 offset 20958255
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   + avc1 size 131 offset 20958271
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + avcC size 45 offset 20958357
|   |   |   |   |   |   + stts size 24 offset 20958402
|   |   |   |   |   |   + stss size 924 offset 20958426
|   |   |   |   |   |   + stsc size 52 offset 20959350
|   |   |   |   |   |   + stsz size 9072 offset 20959402
|   |   |   |   |   |   + stco size 9064 offset 20968474
|   |   + trak size 47341 offset 20977538
|   |   |   + tkhd size 92 offset 20977546
|   |   |   + edts size 36 offset 20977638
|   |   |   |   + elst size 28 offset 20977646
|   |   |   + mdia size 47205 offset 20977674
|   |   |   |   + mdhd size 32 offset 20977682
|   |   |   |   + hdlr size 45 offset 20977714
|   |   |   |   + minf size 47120 offset 20977759
|   |   |   |   |   + smhd size 16 offset 20977767
|   |   |   |   |   + dinf size 36 offset 20977783
|   |   |   |   |   |   + dref size 28 offset 20977791
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   + url  size 12 offset 20977807
|   |   |   |   |   + stbl size 47060 offset 20977819
|   |   |   |   |   |   + stsd size 106 offset 20977827
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   + mp4a size 90 offset 20977843
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + esds size 54 offset 20977879
|   |   |   |   |   |   + stts size 2056 offset 20977933
|   |   |   |   |   |   + stsc size 22756 offset 20979989
|   |   |   |   |   |   + stsz size 13016 offset 21002745
|   |   |   |   |   |   + stco size 9064 offset 21015761
|   |   |   |   |   |   + sgpd size 26 offset 21024825
|   |   |   |   |   |   + sbgp size 28 offset 21024851
|   |   + udta size 98 offset 21024879
|   |   |   + meta size 90 offset 21024887
|   |   |   |   + hdlr size 33 offset 21024899
|   |   |   |   + ilst size 45 offset 21024932
|   |   |   |   |   + ctoo size 37 offset 21024940
|   |   |   |   |   |   + data size 29 offset 21024948
ISO Media (isom) version 512.
found 2 tracks
elst box found
   - [0] duration=75434ms media time=0ms) rate=1.0
track[Id 0x1] read 2262 chunk
STTS table of 1 entries
track[Id 0x1] read 2263 samples length:75s
selecting program id=0
adding track[Id 0x1] video (enable) language undef
elst box found
   - [0] duration=75453ms media time=0ms) rate=1.0
track[Id 0x2] read 2262 chunk
STTS table of 255 entries
track[Id 0x2] read 3249 samples length:75s
adding track[Id 0x2] audio (enable) language undef
using demux module "mp4"
looking for packetizer module matching "any": 25 candidates
found NAL_SPS (sps_id=0)
found NAL_PPS (pps_id=0 sps_id=0)
Packetizer fed with AVC, nal length size=4
using packetizer module "h264"
looking for packetizer module matching "any": 25 candidates
running MPEG4 audio packetizer
AACv2 44100Hz 1024 samples/frame
using packetizer module "mpeg4audio"
starting in sync mode
looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\frank\AppData\Local\Packages\c8e7ca88-7e68-45b6-80bb-9d3c1a5a38e1_h68e2gsmfdepg\LocalState\vlc\lua\meta\reader
no meta reader modules matched
`imem://' successfully opened
elst (0) gives 0ms (movie)-> 0ms (track)
track[Id 0x1] using Sync Sample Box (stss)
stss gives 0 --> 0 (sample number)
elst (0) gives 0ms (movie)-> 0ms (track)
Buffering 0%
switching to async mode
Buffering 83%
adding a new sout input for `h264` (sout_input: 103E2570)
creating video transcoding from fcc=`h264' to fcc=`mp2v'
looking for video decoder module matching "any": 14 candidates
using ffmpeg Lavc58.134.100
CPU flags: 0x000fd3db
Stream buffering done (500 ms in 8 ms)
allowing 6 thread(s) for decoding
adding a new sout input for `mp4a` (sout_input: 103E2588)
codec (h264) started
using frame thread mode with 6 threads
looking for encoder module matching "any": 18 candidates
using video decoder module "avcodec"
using ffmpeg Lavc58.134.100
CPU flags: 0x000fd3db
Time base for probing set to 1000/25000
Time base set to 1/25
rc buffer size 16384000 bits
Unknown option "rc_buffer_aggressivity"
found encoder MPEG-2 Video
using encoder module "avcodec"
removing module "avcodec"
creating audio transcoding from fcc=`mp4a' to fcc=`mpga'
looking for audio decoder module matching "any": 19 candidates
using ffmpeg Lavc58.134.100
CPU flags: 0x000fd3db
codec (aac) started
using audio decoder module "avcodec"
looking for encoder module matching "any": 18 candidates
using ffmpeg Lavc58.134.100
CPU flags: 0x000fd3db
Trying to find more suitable sample format instead of s16
Ended up using s16 as sample format
Creating channel order for reordering
0 1 mapped to 2
1 2 mapped to 4
found encoder MPEG Audio layer 1/2
using encoder module "avcodec"
input 'f32l' 44100 Hz Mono frame=1 samples/4 bytes
conversion: 'f32l'->'s16l' 44100 Hz->44100 Hz Mono->Stereo
looking for audio converter module matching "any": 7 candidates
using audio converter module "trivial"
looking for audio converter module matching "any": 7 candidates
f32l->s16l, bits per sample: 32->16
using audio converter module "audio_format"
conversion pipeline complete
looking for audio resampler module matching "any": 2 candidates
using audio resampler module "ugly"
removing module "avcodec"
removing module "ugly"
removing module "trivial"
removing module "audio_format"
Decoder wait done in 19 ms
looking for encoder module matching "any": 18 candidates
using ffmpeg Lavc58.134.100
CPU flags: 0x000fd3db
Trying to find more suitable sample format instead of s16
Ended up using s16 as sample format
Creating channel order for reordering
0 1 mapped to 2
1 2 mapped to 4
found encoder MPEG Audio layer 1/2
available hardware decoder output format 118 (d3d11va_vld)
using encoder module "avcodec"
available hardware decoder output format 174 (d3d11)
input 'f32l' 44100 Hz Mono frame=1 samples/4 bytes
available software decoder output format 0 (yuv420p)
conversion: 'f32l'->'s16l' 44100 Hz->44100 Hz Mono->Stereo
looking for audio converter module matching "any": 7 candidates
using audio converter module "trivial"
looking for audio converter module matching "any": 7 candidates
f32l->s16l, bits per sample: 32->16
using audio converter module "audio_format"
conversion pipeline complete
looking for audio resampler module matching "any": 2 candidates
using audio resampler module "ugly"
adding a new input
adding input codec=mpga pid=200
new PCR PID is 200
trying format d3d11va_vld
Checking if filter chain DX11 -> I420 is possible
looking for video converter module matching "any": 22 candidates
using video converter module "d3d11_filters"
Filter 'd3d11_filters' (115B0F20) appended to chain
removing module "d3d11_filters"
Filter 115B0F20 removed from chain
Filter chain testing done, input chroma DX11 seems to be possible for transcode
looking for hw decoder module matching "any": 1 candidates
Created the D3D11 device type 1 level b100.
CreateDevice succeed
- 'MPEG-2 variable-length decoder' is supported
- 'MPEG-2 & MPEG-1 variable-length decoder' is supported
- 'H.264 variable-length decoder, no film grain technology' is supported
- 'H.264 variable-length decoder, no film grain technology, Flash' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0x6719b6fb-0x5cad-0x4acb-0xb00af3bfdec38727' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0x9901ccd3-0xca12-0x4b7e-0x867ae2223d9255c3' is supported
- 'HEVC Main profile' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0xea72396a-0x67ec-0x4781-0xbede56f498f04ef2' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0xc152ca8f-0x738c-0x461b-0xad89fc292cf8f162' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0x514a356c-0x7027-0x4aff-0x8a60afd2c1f672f1' is supported
- 'H.264 stereo high profile, mbs flag set' is supported
- 'H.264 stereo high profile' is supported
|   |   + trak size 19576 offset 20957962
- 'VC-1 variable-length decoder' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0xca15d19a-0x2b48-0x43d6-0x979e7a6e9c802ff8' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0xd1c20509-0xae7b-0x4e72-0xae3b49f88d58992f' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0x84ad67f6-0x4c21-0x419a-0x9f0b24f0578906c1' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0x725ad240-0x786c-0x471e-0xad3c38f739936517' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0x95664ff5-0x9e03-0x4c74-0xbb4f9178d6035e58' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0x5ef7d40d-0x5b96-0x49e7-0xb41923342094a4cf' is supported
- 'HEVC Main 10 profile' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0x65d1fa41-0x58af-0x453a-0x9cab5d981156da9f' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0x2db154b6-0xdbb2-0x4079-0xa3ff60d7a898a6ab' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0xc74a3fd0-0xd713-0x4581-0xa02e8edfb112ace3' is supported
- 'VP9 profile 0' is supported
- 'VP9 profile 2' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0x603a4756-0xa864-0x4f91-0xbb622c935b7a1391' is supported
- 'Unknown decoder 0xc58b9a06-0x7e89-0x11e1-0xbb0070b34824019b' is supported
Trying to use 'H.264 variable-length decoder, no film grain technology' as input
NV12 output is supported for decoder H.264 variable-length decoder, no film grain technology.
Using output format NV12 for decoder H.264 variable-length decoder, no film grain technology
va_pool_SetupDecoder id 27 1280x720 count: 24
ID3D11VideoDecoderOutputView succeed with 24 surfaces (1280x720)
we got 7 decoder configurations
configuration[0] ConfigBitstreamRaw 2
configuration[1] ConfigBitstreamRaw 2
configuration[2] ConfigBitstreamRaw 2
configuration[3] ConfigBitstreamRaw 2
configuration[5] ConfigBitstreamRaw 2
configuration[4] ConfigBitstreamRaw 2
configuration[6] ConfigBitstreamRaw 2
DxCreateDecoderSurfaces succeed
using hw decoder module "d3d11va"
Using D3D11VA (AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics, vendor 1002(ATI), device 1636, revision c2) for hardware decoding
source fps 30/1, destination 25/1
decoder aspect is 1.777778:1
source pixel aspect is 1.000000:1
scaled pixel aspect is 1.000000:1
source 1280x720, destination 1280x720
encoder aspect is 1280:720
source chroma: DX11, destination I420
looking for video converter module matching "any": 22 candidates
using video converter module "d3d11_filters"
Filter 'd3d11_filters' (115B19A0) appended to chain
destination (after video filters) 1280x720
looking for encoder module matching "any": 18 candidates
using ffmpeg Lavc58.134.100
CPU flags: 0x000fd3db
Time base for probing set to 1/25
Time base set to 1/25
rc buffer size 16384000 bits
Unknown option "rc_buffer_aggressivity"
found encoder MPEG-2 Video
using encoder module "avcodec"
adding a new input
adding input codec=mp2v pid=100
new PCR PID is 100
almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (17574504)
|   + ftyp size 32 offset 0
|   + free size 8 offset 32
|   + mdat size 20957806 offset 40
|   + moov size 67131 offset 20957846
|   |   |   + tkhd size 92 offset 20957970
|   |   |   + edts size 36 offset 20958062
almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (17574509)
almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (17574514)
almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (17576369)
many more of the messages until
EOF reached
waiting decoder fifos to empty
almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (17576374)
almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (17576379)
The thread 0x5fc8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
killing decoder fourcc `h264'
removing module "h264"
removing a sout input (sout_input: 103E2570)
almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (17576384)
cannot encode one frame
removing module "avcodec"
The thread 0x48b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
removing module "avcodec"
removing module "d3d11_filters"
Filter 115B19A0 removed from chain
removing input pid=100
new PCR PID is 200
The thread 0x1b6c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
freeing video PID 100
cannot encode one frame
removing module "avcodec"
removing module "avcodec"
removing module "trivial"
removing input pid=200
freeing audio PID 200
no more input streams for this mux
removing module "mp4"
Program doesn't contain anymore ES
removing module "cache_read"
removing module "audio_format"
Flushing..
removing module "mpeg4audio"
removing a sout input (sout_input: 103E2588)
killing decoder fourcc `mp4a'
removing module "ugly"
freeing all memory
removing module "imem_access"
removing module "record"
Stooped. Wir können kopieren
The thread 0x2e68 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Basic Properties: 0 + 2/24/2022 9:26:07 PM +01:00
Video Properties:  mit 00:00:00
destroying useless sout
removing module "winstore"
destroying chain done
removing module "stream_out_standard"
removing module "mux_ts"
destroying chain... (name=std)
destroying chain done
removing module "stream_out_transcode"
removing module "file"
destroying chain... (name=transcode)
file access output closed
The thread 0x16f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: I don't think `AddSlave` has the same behavior as `--sub-file`

Comment: I have tried it with --sub-file also but without any success so far.

Comment: Did you have a look at the logs ? https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/3.x/docs/troubleshooting.md

Comment: I recognized one more thing: The AddSlave method only returns true when it is used after the Play method. But the output is without any subtitles.

Comment: Added the log to the description.